# Crystal Reports delay shows old data when using MS Access

Tags: visual-studio-2010, ms-access, crystal-reports-xi

Here is in interesting one.

I have a Crystal Report that uses a single Microsoft Access 2007 table. The data in the table is updated at run time based on criteria from a list box.

If I select one entry from my list it updates the data and shows in the report. If I select and different entry is shows the data the old data. If i select that report enough times it will eventually show the new data.

The data in the access data base is updated as I checked manually

My problem is that there seems to be a delay in between the data updating and the report showing the new data.

Is there anyway to reduce this delay or get my program to wait until access has finished updating ?

Answer (score 0):

Here's some ideas:

If you're mixing cr-xi with VS2010, and have no real reason to do so, then uninstall xi and install the new libraries for VS2010. I had issues mixing cr-xi with VS2010.

There's an option to save data with report. Make sure that's turned off. If it already was, turn it on, run the report, then turn it off again.

You can try rpt.Refresh(), right before crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rpt.

[This page](http://scn.sap.com/thread/3151988) had some ideas, including the last one I listed.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I did try the .Refresh option and .ReportSource is set new each time I select the report from my listbox. I have the very latest libraries for CR-XI/VS2010. I'll check the link you sent.

Comment: I just tried everything in that post, and some other related posts and I still have the same problem and I have checked everything. Any other suggestions

Comment: I thought my problem was solved but actually isnt. My problem is that end users will be responsible for installing the applications with no technical support. They are contract staff and we have no liability for them. The chances of them installing MS SQL Express is nil. They have no technical experience. They can barely use a computer so any install needs to be easy. The application and support files is a single click install. Please Help.